# How to remove temporary commits in Git?

Tags: git, commit

I have a habit to make "senseless" commits sometimes, for example, to fix intermediate state of unfinished refactoring. Other example are very small commits, for example, typo fixes.

I am writing "TEMP" prefix in such commit descriptions.

Can I delete these commits later, i.e. remove logical point in code change history, but simultaneously keep all code changes? Does git have means for this?

Comment: Are you trying to describe an interactive rebase? Or just amend your previous commit, if you don't see them as being separate.

Comment: use stash instead

Comment: I use interactive rebase for these.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you're currently checked out on your temporary commit, you can:

- Finish your work and combine it with the temporary commit, using `git commit --amend`;
- Unwrap your temporary commit into your working tree, using `git reset --mixed HEAD~`;
- Pile up as many temporary commits as you wish and combine them with `git rebase -i` and squashes.